# No supported authentication methods available [preauth]

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, sshd, ssh-keys

I have a problem with logging using public key genereted with puttygen. My `/var/log/auth.log` says

```
No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
```

When attempting to connect using putty I receive error:

```
Server refused our key
Disconnected: No supported authentification methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

Seems like key file generated by puttygen is not compatible with openssh.

I found no working solution in internet

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibities here:

1. You should start pagent and load your private key before you try to connect to an ssh server
2. The `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file has incorrect permissions (should have `0600`)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `.ppk` file really contains a key in PuTTY format (starts with `PuTTY-User-...`)

Sometimes people put PEM format there (starts with `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`), esp when copy&paste keys from one workstation to another.